# BigQuery API query job return 404 for existing dataset

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am running into a problem while using BigQuery API in Python.

I have set up a bigquery Client 
`bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id, location=location)`
and it works like expected. 
`datasets = list(client.list_datasets())` 
Returns the list of datasets in the project.

```
%%bigquery --project project_id df
SELECT *
FROM `cached.csv_reports_sessions_report`
```

Magics request works and creates the required dataframe.

However, if I try to create the same dataframe from a query job like so:

```
sql = """
    SELECT *
    FROM `cached.csv_reports_sessions_report`
    LIMIT 100
"""
df = client.query(sql, project=project_id).to_dataframe()
```

I get the following error: 404 Not found: Dataset project_id:cached was not found in location europe-west3. The location is correct location for the project and dataset.

I have tried using the full path including the project_id like so: 
`project_id.cached.csv_reports_sessions_report`
Still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I found out the problem. I have declared my location as 'europe-west3' which is the actual location, but it seems for the query job it was too specific. It started working fine after declaring location as simply 'EU'